# React Native What is the fastest way of rendering view among using react state and redux state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have used react-native-maps on iOS and Android, also I am using many markers on the map.

So I really need to render view more fast as far as I can.

Among these ways below, What is the fastest way ?

### Only Redux

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  a: state.a
});

render() {
  return (
    this.props.a ? (<View>isA</View>) : (<View>isNotA</View>)
  );
}
```

### React State from Redux

```
state = { a: false }

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.a !== prevState.a) {
    return ({ a: nextProps.a })
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    this.state.a ? (<View>isA</View>) : (<View>isNotA</View>)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would load the props before I even get to the view. Let's say you need the data on page B
to get to page B you need to click a button on page A.

When page A is loaded, you request the data needed for page B. When navigating to page B you simply pass the properties via a router and you have them available from start in page B component.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I meant that "Is it exist the gap of speed when doing not complicated work, for example, something just like to pass prop (bool, string, etc..) ?"

Comment: I wonder that is it exists the gap of speed when just receiving props using the ways above from parent component.

Comment: Your comment is not suitable on this issue, but very helped to me in other use cases. Thanks.